# ¿Cómo hago para que al redirigir a una página con action no se me acople la ruta nueva a la ruta actual?

Tags: html, xampp

Uso un xampp y me gustaría que una página redirigiese a otra que tengo en el directorio htdocs pero se me monta la ruta encima de donde esta ahora mismo.
tengo un archivo que se llama prueba.html con este código.

```
 <form action="localhost\htdocs\prueba1.php">
```

pero cuando lo uso el la url que me da es

```
http://localhost/plantilla/localhost/plantilla/prueba1.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza en el `action` una ruta absoluta:

```
 <form action="http://localhost/htdocs/prueba1.php">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, mira que he tratado de todo tipo de cosas y no me acordaba de eso.